# Call the official Settings app in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, settings, social-framework

From what I read, in iOS 5 you could call the Settings app with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General"]]
```

but in iOS 5.1 it was no longer available.

However, in iOS 6, in Social framework you can do this with Facebook and Twitter.
Is there a way to replicate this for when you need to set up an account for mail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is no way to do this, Apple has not released a URL scheme for the settings app.